# Skip empty list from persistence in Spring Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa

I have a Spring application that uses `MongoTemplate` to write to MongoDB. The problem is that I want to skip empty list entity properties from persistence to save some space around the docuemnt. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When defining your schema model, you can set `default: undefined` config for that property.

```js
const schema= new Schema({
  property_1: { type: Array, default: undefined },
})
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I would like to avoid hardcode any property names. Was more looking for some config on the application side